# splash screen in pubspec.yaml throws error A dependency may only have one source

Tags: splash-screen

i'm trying to get splash screen working. according to pub.dev i install it into pubspec.yaml the way i have it. I've seen a video of someone else using it the way i have it and it works for them. I've included a snippet of what i have. The error i'm getting is

I have searched on this forum and read the solutions but i'm still getting the same error. I've tried changing min to max version, i've tried moving splashscreen around to different parts of pubspec.yaml

```
    dependencies:  
  
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  splashscreen: ^1.3.5

dev_dependencies:  
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I've also tried splashscreen: ">=1.2.0 <1.3.5" just incase that could work. Please someone tell me how to get this working. Why i want this to work so bad is i see it shows loading icon right at the bottom to show the user the app is loading.

Comment: i have tried `splashscreen: ^1.3.5` nothing and it worked like a charm , can you provide the error code ?

Comment: @FahmiSawalha 
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
exit code 65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting it under "dependencies" and left it there. I carried on working on the rest of the project, eventually after 1 day splashscreen got accepted, i really didn't do anything.